# How do you use SOAP::Lite?

Tags: linux, perl, soap

I am very new to linux and perl and I am trying to use SOAP::Lite as an API for ffencoderd, a daemon to convert my videos in background. I know I am probably doing something stupid but I read the documentation [SOAP::Lite](http://guide.soaplite.com/#quick%20start%20guide%20with%20soap%20and%20soap%3a%3alite) and is says to type use SOAP::Lite. I type into the terminal use SOAP::Lite and it says 'no command use'. So I try perl use SOAP::Lite and it says no directory use...Can someone give me some clarity here lol, I feel pretty dumb right now...

Comment: I've encountered lots of issues with SOAP::Lite. I suggest you start with another SOAP module.

Comment: @ikegami: Can you suggest an easier one for beginners? SOAP::Lite seems to be advocated as 'the easiest' all around?

Comment: I don't see how it can be advocated as easiest. It was the *only* option. Others have surfaces, and they are equally if not easier to use, and don't have all the bugs of SOAP::Lite. I can't give a name, since I haven't done SOAP since wrestling with SOAP::Lite.

Comment: I see [SOAP::WSDL](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?SOAP::WSDL) and [XML::Compile::SOAP](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?XML::Compile::SOAP). The former looks easy to use, and I think it's the one I saw recommended.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your problem seems to be that you don't know Perl, rather then that you don't know SOAP::Lite. You might like to start with the [Modern Perl book](http://www.onyxneon.com/books/modern_perl/index.html) (in hard copy or a free ebook).

SOAP::Lite is a module, not an executable, so you don't run it directly from the command line.

`use` is part of the Perl language, not an executable, so again, you can't run it directly from the command line.

You could write a Perl one-liner that calls it

```
perl -MSOAP::Lite -E'your perl code here'
```

… but SOAP is sufficiently complicated that a one-liner almost certainly isn't what you are after.

You need to open a text file, put the standard Perl boilerplate at the top (a shebang line along with `use strict; use warnings;`) and then write your program there (so you can save it).

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use SOAP::Lite;
```

then you can run the script you saved:

```
perl path/to/your.pl
```

Comment: Thanks Quentin, appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Going from not knowing anything about Perl (which is, I assume, your current situation) to using complex modules like SOAP::Lite is a pretty big leap. I'd really recommend working your way up to it over a period of some months.

But if your requirement is more urgent, then my best advice would be to hire a Perl programmer.